# I want to split the window url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.exemple.local/en/node/28
```

I want to split only the `en` part and insert it in another div. My code is something like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var urlDomaine = document.location.origin
var splitedUrl = url.split(urlDomaine)[1];
console.log(splitedUrl);
$('.div').text(splitedUrl);
```

This will print to me the `/en/node/28` and I don't want to split it again, any ideas?

Comment: Split it with /

Comment: Can you confirm exactly what you want out? Is it `/node/28`?

Comment: Do you just want `en`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to hack the string around with `split()`, or any other convoluted methods.

Simply use `window.location.pathname`. When run on the URL you've specified this will return:

```
/en/node/28
```

If you only want the `en` value, split the `pathName` then retrieve the second element of the resulting array:

```
var pathName = window.location.pathName; // = '/en/node/28'
var lang = pathName.split('/')[1]; // = 'en'
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP wants. Seems like this is already what their code returns and they want to modify that string they return further down. May be mistaken though

Comment: I think you may well be correct. I'll be happy to amend/delete this if the OP can edit their question to specify *exactly* what output they are trying to retrieve.

Comment: This is exaclty what i want, works just fine Man (y)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Don't forget to accept an answer, if it helped

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you are looking for something like this (using Web Api's [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)):

```js
var url = 'http://www.exemple.local/en/node/28' 
var myURLObj = new URL(url);


console.log(myURLObj.pathname)   // '/en/node/28'
console.log(myURLObj.pathname.split('/')[1]);   // 'en'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use ES6 destructuring feature to break down your full url into it's various parts:

```js
var path = 'http://www.exemple.local/en/node/28'
let [protocol, url, locale, node, id] = path.split('/').filter(chunk => chunk.length);

console.log(protocol);
console.log(url);
console.log(locale);
console.log(node);
console.log(id);
```